# Appcelerator - androdi.support.v4

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

When I compile the project this error appears:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to compile Java source files:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Manager/build/android/gen/es/renr/manager/ManagerActivity.java:5: error: cannot access TaskStackBuilder
[ERROR] :  public final class ManagerActivity extends TiRootActivity
[ERROR] :               ^
[ERROR] :    class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found
[ERROR] :  /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Manager/build/android/gen/es/renr/manager/ManagerApplication.java:149: error: cannot access FragmentActivity
[ERROR] :       org.appcelerator.titanium.TiVerify verify = new org.appcelerator.titanium.TiVerify(rootActivity, this);
[ERROR] :                                                   ^
[ERROR] :    class file for android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not found
[ERROR] :  Note: /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Manager/build/android/gen/es/renr/manager/AssetCryptImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[ERROR] :  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[ERROR] :  2 errors
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/acavero/.appcelerator/install/4.0.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:84:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I haven't got any idea to what is happening...

It's an appcelerator project (alloy) so I can't add de library (.jar) to the project I think..

Please help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** SOLUTION ****

The only solution I found is include a module with this library. But it's a pity have to create a module only for this library...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to bring this up in the official Q&A at http://community.appcelerator.com and include information about the Titanium SDK and Android min/target versions set in your tiapp.xml.

Comment: I put this in the official Q&A too.